pushing to tidb causes an error with prisma mysql
I'm using TIDB which is a mysql db
when I'm pushing with prisma it gives me an error yet still pushed the data?
first time I pushed it didnt cause any errors yet when I try now it does, I dont have much else to add but can't post due to "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." so Im just typing
.env
DATABASE_URL='mysql://dQGUvqJrGU77inw.root:1v3jgSCfBHcY6lH7@gateway01.eu-central-1.prod.aws.tidbcloud.com:4000/test?sslaccept=strict'

schema.prisma
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["fullTextSearch", "fullTextIndex"]
}

datasource db {
  provider     = "mysql"
  url          = env("DATABASE_URL")
  relationMode = "prisma"
}

model Category {
  id         String @id @default(uuid())
  name       String
  companions Companion[]
}

model Companion {
  id           String @id @default(uuid())
  userId       String
  userName     String
  src          String
  seed         String @db.Text
  name         String @db.Text
  instructions String @db.Text
  description  String
  categoryId   String
  createdAt    DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt    DateTime @updatedAt
  category     Category @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  messages     Message[]

  @@index([categoryId])
  @@fulltext([name])
}

enum Role {
  user
  system
}

model Message {
  id          String @id @default(uuid())
  userId      String
  companionId String
  content     String @db.Text
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt
  role        Role

  companion Companion @relation(fields: [companionId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@index([companionId])
}

console
PS C:\Users\anato\OneDrive\Desktop\ai-companions> npx prisma generate
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma

✔ Generated Prisma Client (v5.17.0) to .\node_modules\@prisma\client in 68ms

Start by importing your Prisma Client (See: http://pris.ly/d/importing-client)

Tip: Want real-time updates to your database without manual polling? Discover how with Pulse: https://pris.ly/tip-0-pulse

PS C:\Users\anato\OneDrive\Desktop\ai-companions> npx prisma db push 
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma
Datasource "db": MySQL database "test" at "gateway01.eu-central-1.prod.aws.tidbcloud.com:4000"
Error: FULLTEXT and SPATIAL index is not supported
   0: sql_schema_connector::apply_migration::migration_step
           with step=CreateIndex { table_id: (Some(TableId(1)), TableId(1)), index_id: IndexId(3), from_drop_and_recreate: false }
             at schema-engine\connectors\sql-schema-connector\src\apply_migration.rs:21
   1: sql_schema_connector::apply_migration::apply_migration
             at schema-engine\connectors\sql-schema-connector\src\apply_migration.rs:10
   2: schema_core::state::SchemaPush
             at schema-engine\core\src\state.rs:461



turns out the simple solution was:
npx prisma migrate reset

@A-Makeyey Hi, just a friendly reminder: it looks like your database password is visible.

its not the real one but thanks
